# IIS and Stand Alone app crashing while setting Parameter on blazor page

Tags: blazor, iis-express

I created the following components as .razor files within a freshly genered blazor server app on asp.net core 3.1:

If you access the page `/P`via either the IIS Express or the .exe stand alone app are crashing with an Access Violation:

> iisexpress.exe" wurde mit Code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access
> violation' beendet.

While debugging it looks like it crashes after setting the `EventCallBack` at the child component.

parent.razor:

```
@page "/P"

<h3>Parent</h3>

Parent: @Name

<Child @bind-Name="Name" />

@code {
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Bla";
}
```

Child.razor

```
<h3>Child</h3>

Value: @Name

@code {
    private string _Name;

    [Parameter]
    public string Name
    {
        get => Name; set
        {
            if (value != _Name)
            {
                _Name = value;
                //NameChanged.InvokeAsync(_Name).Wait();
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> NameChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Within the next step I want to change the `Name` field within the child component and use the callback function to send the changes to the parent.

Do anyone have an solution or an idea to get more information?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I would suggest for you to try to get you moving along;

On the child component , define the `EventCallback` as a parameter. Add some mechanism for changing the `Name` and then invoking the `EventCallback`. In this example I have used a text box (with two way binding to keep the `Name` property up to date) and a button to invoke the callback.

```
<h3>Child</h3>

<input @bind-Value="Name" /> 
<button @onclick="OnButtonClicked" >Click me</button>

@code {    
    [Parameter]
    public string Name {get; set;} 

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> NameChanged {get; set;}

    public async Task OnButtonClicked(){
        await NameChanged.InvokeAsync(Name);
    }
}
```

On parent page set a default string in the page initialisation, then bind this to the child component. Also define an event handler for the name change which is bubbled from the child component.;

```
@page "/mypage"

<h3>Parent</h3>

Parent: @Name

<Child Name="@Name" NameChanged="HandleNameChanged" }

@code {
    public string Name { get; set; }
   
    public override void OnInitialized(){
       Name = "bla";
    }

    public void HandleNameChanged(string changedName){
       Name = changedName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your quick answer ... sorry for being unclear on my question. Within the next step I want to change the namefield within the child component and use de callback function to send the changes to the parent.

Comment: How are you changing the name? With a text box or something?

Comment: I've updated the example to show this with a textbox and button to make a change on the child component. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer ... its a typo at the getter on the shout be `get => _Name` to access the backing field.

So it goes goes to an infinite loop which will lead to the crash...